# does 0 and 1 always have quadratic residue?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

When we discuss quadratic residues, it tends to leave out the case when p = 2.

For example $(\frac{-1}{p}) = 1$ if p = 1 mod 4. p here is an odd prime. I am wondering what if p = 2, does 0 and 1 always have quadratic residue?

Comment: You can just square all two elements modulo 2 and see when you get a square ...

Comment: So it is true that 0 and 1 always have quadratic residue?

Comment: They don't _have_ quadratic residues, they always _are_ quadratic residues for any prime, since $9^2 \equiv 0$ and $1^2 = 1$.